# Why doesn't H₄CO₄ exist as a stable compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, carbon-family

Why doesn't $\ce{H4CO4}$ exist as a relatively stable compound? Its heavier homologue $\ce{H4SiO4}$ seems to exist although it is unstable to some extent but new methods have been able to stabilise orthosilicic acid using choline chloride.

Comment: It is called orthocarbonic acid and it does not exist.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocarbonic_acid

Comment: @NilayGhosh I just couldn't explain what I mean so I changed the question

Comment: Imho, this is a perfectly fine question and there is no reason for it to be closed.

Comment: I also think it shouldn't be close

Comment: Perhaps the question should be changed to "why is H4CO4 -> H2CO3 + H2O a favorable reaction but H4SiO4 -> H2SiO3 + H2O is not?"

Answer (score 6):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocarbonic_acid) reports that calculations show orthocarbonic acid spontaneously decomposes to the ordinary (meta)carbonic acid $\ce{H2CO3}$ plus water.  However, orthocarbonate esters $\ce{C(OR)4}$ do exist, and more recently salts with the alkaline earth metals have been synthesized under conditions matching the deep mantle of Earth.

The orthoacid may, however, become stable at high pressure [[1](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep32486), with a nontechnical summary given in [2](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3777582/What-lies-beneath-Uranus-Neptune-Weird-materials-like-Hitler-s-Acid-lurk-inside-planets.html)] and possibly exist within Uranus and Neptune.  It is further posited that $\ce{H2CO3}$, ordinarily only a minor species in aqueous solution, becomes a stable solid in the interiors of some icy moons, possibly impacting interactions thought to be necessary for the development of subterranean life.

A final note: the swastika-like shape of the orthocarbonic acid molecule has led unfortunately to the name "Hitler's acid".  Actually the swastika long predates the Nazis and retains non-Nazi usages to this day.